# How to convert an asynchronous function into synchronous function using promise in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, api

I have changed my code with async as suggested I am still not able to access the value and getting the error of Cannot read property '0' of undefined.The task_id is not accessible by the third function as its not created:

```
 app.post('/api/add_task',function(req,res,error){
  var sql = "INSERT INTO `campus_ambassador`.`tasks` ( `task_type`, `task_name`, `details`, `social_media_handles`, `media`, `created_date`, `updated_date`) VALUES ('offline', 'golfed', 'ssss', '#soccer', 'sdfsd', '2012-12-26 00:00:00', '2012-12-26 00:00:00');"
  var sql1 = "select task_id from tasks where task_name='golfed'";
  var sql2 = "INSERT INTO `campus_ambassador`.`task_level` (`task_id`, `level_id`, `updated_on`, `created_on`) VALUES ("+"'"+res1[0].task_id+"'"+", '3', '2012-12-26 00:00:00', '2012-12-26 00:00:00')";
  var res1=''

  async.waterfall([
  function(callback){  
      db.select(sql,function(err){
          console.log("made the task");
          callback(null);

          })

      },

      function(callback){
  db.select(sql1,function(err,data){
                res1 = data;
                console.log(res1);
                console.log(res1[0].task_id);
                console.log("got the task id of the created task")
                res.end();
                 callback(null,data);   
                    })
          },
    function(callback){
              db.select(sql2,function(err){
              console.log(res1[0].task_id)
            console.log("updated the task level table")
            callback(null);
          })
       }

 ],
    function(err,results){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    })
})
```

Comment: Why do you need promises there? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Promises won't make your code any more synchronous, they're just another way to write async code.

Comment: 2nd function is dependant on the 1st on and 2nd is dependant on the 3rd one

Comment: its like its creating a new task and then i need to get the task id of the newly created task and then map that taskid into the level-task table

Comment: is this not the way to go @IamNguele

Comment: As I see it using promises will make your code harder to read and to maintain as is. To make it cleaner you would need to put each operation in its own function and make each function return a promise that would have its `resolve, reject` callbacks made based on each result.

Comment: what is the best way to do it then @IamNguele

Comment: can you help me with a example @IamNguele

Comment: Look into async and await  or `then`.

Comment: @k0pernikus i have been trying to use async. with the following code

Comment: I said async *and await*. That will be the most readable solution.

Answer (score 2):

This actually depend on a few things. What version of node you are using and if your lib for db support promise.

**Turning callback into promise**

If your db doesnt support promise by default you have to do it yourself, like this:

```
var dbSelectPromise = function(db, sql) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.select(sql, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

**Using the promise**

Once you have it as a promise (either you made it, or it is native from your db) you can use it like this

```
dbSelectPromise(db, sql)
.then(function(fristResult) {
    return dbSelectPromise(db, sql1)
})
.then(function(secondResult) {
    return dbSelectPromise(db, sql2)
})
.then(function(thirdResult) {
    // And so on...
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // Here you can handle errors for all of them
})
```

**Using async/await**

If your node version is 7.6 or higher you can do even better. Frist change the promise function:

```
var dbSelectPromise(db, sql) = async function {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.select(sql, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Then you can use it like sync code:

```
var fristResult = await dbSelectPromise(db, sql)
var secontResult = await dbSelectPromise(db, sql1)
var thirdResult = await dbSelectPromise(db, sql2)
```

**EDIT**
To save the result accross multiples "then" you can save the result in the outer scope, like so:

```
var frist, second, third
dbSelectPromise(db, sql)
.then(function(fristResult) {
    frist = fristResult
    return dbSelectPromise(db, sql1)
})
.then(function(secondResult) {
    second = secondResult
    return dbSelectPromise(db, sql2)
})
.then(function(thirdResult) {
    third = thirdResult
    // And so on...
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // Here you can handle errors for all of them
})
```

Comment: In order to promisfy async functions with a callback, there are helpers out there, e.g. [Bluebird's promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html). And the beauty of the await solution is that one can `try {await stuff() } catch (e) {...}`

Comment: How do i access to the result of the previous promise

Comment: I added it to add it